# My grid-items won't go under each other by responsive

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a problem with my grid-items.
When i resize my windows they go perfectly from 2 rows to 3 rows.
But when I go smaller they won't take the 100% width of the screen and also won't go under each other.
I might be missing a small detail after long coding.
I am also new with grid.

if anyone can help me out with this would be awesome!

```css
/* img column update information */

.img-column {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 50px 30px;
  margin-top: 4.5rem;
}

.update-block {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
}

.update-block:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.update-block:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.img-block img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.figure {
  border-left: 22vw solid var(--primary-color);
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56.3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-column">

  <div class="update-block">
    <div class="img-block">
      <img src="./images/photo6.png" alt="picture">
    </div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="img-p">
      <p>LOREM IPSUMA DOLOR SIT.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="update-block">
    <div class="img-block">
      <img src="./images/photo5.png" alt="picture">
    </div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="img-p">
      <p>LOREM IPSUMA DOLOR SIT.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="update-block">
    <div class="img-block">
      <img src="./images/photo4.png" alt="picture">
    </div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="img-p">
      <p>LOREM IPSUMA DOLOR SIT.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="update-block">
    <div class="img-block">
      <img src="./images/photo1.png" alt="picture">
    </div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="img-p">
      <p>LOREM IPSUMA DOLOR SIT.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="update-block">
    <div class="img-block">
      <img src="./images/photo2.png" alt="picture">
    </div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="img-p">
      <p>LOREM IPSUMA DOLOR SIT.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="update-block">
    <div class="img-block">
      <img src="./images/photo3.png" alt="picture">
    </div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="img-p">
      <p>LOREM IPSUMA DOLOR SIT.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@media` for different css for different screen sizes
`@media (max-height: 350px)`

```css
/* img column update information */

.img-column {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 50px 30px;
  margin-top: 4.5rem;
}

.update-block {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
}

.update-block:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.update-block:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.img-block img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.figure {
  border-left: 22vw solid var(--primary-color);
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56.3%;
}

/* here a change*/
@media (max-height: 350px) { 
  .update-block:nth-child(5), .update-block:nth-child(6) {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  
  .img-column { 
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); 
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="img-column">

  <div class="update-block">
    <div class="img-block">
      <img src="./images/photo6.png" alt="picture">
    </div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="img-p">
      <p>LOREM IPSUMA DOLOR SIT.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="update-block">
    <div class="img-block">
      <img src="./images/photo5.png" alt="picture">
    </div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="img-p">
      <p>LOREM IPSUMA DOLOR SIT.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="update-block">
    <div class="img-block">
      <img src="./images/photo4.png" alt="picture">
    </div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="img-p">
      <p>LOREM IPSUMA DOLOR SIT.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="update-block">
    <div class="img-block">
      <img src="./images/photo1.png" alt="picture">
    </div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="img-p">
      <p>LOREM IPSUMA DOLOR SIT.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="update-block">
    <div class="img-block">
      <img src="./images/photo2.png" alt="picture">
    </div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="img-p">
      <p>LOREM IPSUMA DOLOR SIT.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="update-block">
    <div class="img-block">
      <img src="./images/photo3.png" alt="picture">
    </div>
    <div class="figure"></div>
    <div class="img-p">
      <p>LOREM IPSUMA DOLOR SIT.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</section>
```